# Sitecore Azure Deployment automation

Tags: azure, deployment, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-azure

I've a TFS CI configured where TDS deploys the Sitecore on to local dev and testing environment, all good.

Eventually our Sitecore will be hosted on to Azure. I'm aware that Sitecore provides and Azure deployment 2.0 tool. From [what I read and saw](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Jakob-Leander/Posts/2013/01/Why-we-love-Sitecore-on-Azure.aspx), it looks like a manual process.

Could someone please help me whether sitecore azure deployment can be somehow automated?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not yet possible :( That's the one thing keeping me from using Sitecore on Azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the PowerShell and WinRM scripting functionality built into PowerCore. You can get a feel for the deployment scenarios that this addresses in the [Push Sitecore solutions to the servers with PowerShell and WinRM](http://sitecoresnippets.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/push-sitecore-solutions-to-servers-with.html) blog post. You can find the code for PowerCore on [GitHub](https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-PowerCore).